# Using regex to escape quotes in SQL Server dump

Tags: sql-server, regex

I'm trying to import a very large database and it appears that there are some quotes that are not well escaped. I already tried using basic regex rules to make a bash script, but there are always exceptions and  even if a managed to escape most of them I can't fix them all.

So a basic INSERT syntax in SQL Server is of this form :

```
INSERT INTO Production.UnitMeasure 
VALUES (N'FT2', N'Square Feet ', '20080923'), 
       (N'Y', N'Yards', '20080923'), 
       (N'Y3', N'Cubic Yards', '20080923');
```

So here it's correct, there is no problem. But for this one :

```
INSERT INTO Production.UnitMeasure 
VALUES (N'FT2', N'Square' Feet ', '20080923'), 
       (N'Y', N'Yards'', '20080923'), 
       (N'Y3', N'CubiN' Yards', '20080923');
```

It's another story. I want to escape all the quotes inside N''. So I would like to get :

```
INSERT INTO Production.UnitMeasure 
VALUES (N'FT2', N'Square'' Feet ', '20080923'), 
       (N'Y', N'Yards''', '20080923'), 
       (N'Y3', N'CubiN'' Yards', '20080923');
```

(A quote escape a quote).

So my idea is to identify every field of the form "N'something'" and then escape the quotes inside "something". I tried to edit an example that I found and I got this :

```
N'((?:.(?!', ))*.)'
```

Edit : [I improved it](http://regex101.com/r/hW5kO5/1)  so that it matches only what's inside N''

So for exemple in perl :

> perl -ne "s/(?<=N')((?:.(?!', ))*.)(')/\1/g;print"

But now I'm trying to escape the quotes that are inside the match, any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: How did the data become corrupt to begin with? :< Anyway, show *how* it is being used in bash - it could trivially be either a quoting or tool (eg. sed) peculiarity.

Comment: can you put a desired output for one statement?

Comment: If you're using raw bash regex strings, I'm not sure it supports lookarounds.

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight is there a way to make it support lookarounds ? Or another way to do it without using lookarounds

Comment: A quick search got me to the conclusion that if you want to use lookarounds you need to use grep with the perl regex engine via `grep -P` or `grep --perl-regexp` [SOURCE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84477/forcing-bash-to-use-perl-regex-engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found the solution :

```
perl -ne "s/(?<!((\(| )N))(?:'{2})*\K(')(?!(, (N'|NULL|CAST|[-0-9])|\)\n))/\3'/g;print"
```

Should escape every odd number of quotes that aren't a delimiter.